# Align items vertically on responsive website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 to develop a responsive website. I have problems with vertical alignment.

1. As you can see on the image, the div in the middle is not centered vertically on the screen. How do I do that?
2. The header is not aligned correctly, I want it to be placed exactly in the middle between the top of the website and the mentioned div. Is there an easy way to do this, so it looks good even on smaller screens?

The website (desktop)
[Website on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq2xk.jpg)

This is how it looks on a mobile:
[Website on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Som7L.jpg)

**HTML Code** [jsfiddle so you get all details!](https://jsfiddle.net/7j6tprqm/)

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: "Abril Fatface";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#headLine {
  font-family: "Abril Fatface";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1%;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#nameLabel,
#gitLabel {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.card {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frontPage">
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex ">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-6 .col-md-6">
      <h1 id="headLine">Let us exam your Git repositories</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="gitForm">
  <div class="container h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class=card>
        <div class="card-block">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="nameLabel" for="projectNameInput">Name your
                                project</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectNameInput" placeholder="A project name you can live with">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="gitLabel" for="repoInput">Enter your Git
                                repository</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id=repoInput placeholder="A valid Gitrepo...">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="submitRepo" onclick="storeRepo()" type="submit">
                              Submit
                          </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: Nice! This solved the problem with the div in the middle! Thank you! Can I use flexbox to center the header between the top of the page and the div?

Comment: sure :) just dig into the flexbox specifications, I suggest you also this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/